# GPIO control in while true:

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, controls, gpio

Hey guys i get all the time the failure:

> photo_booth.py:18: RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use, continuing anyway.  Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings.
>     GPIO.setup(RELAI, GPIO.OUT)

I also try to control al relays with the `GPIO 18` but it is not working at all. 
I tried it with some others but nothing changed. the relais i all the time on and it is not turning off with the command. what is my problem?

can you please tell me the problem ?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO, time, os, subprocess, signal

# GPIO setup

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

SWITCH = 24
GPIO.setup(SWITCH, GPIO.IN)
RESET = 25
GPIO.setup(RESET, GPIO.IN)
RELAI = 19
GPIO.setup(RELAI, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(RELAI, GPIO.LOW)
j = 0
k = 0

def entprellen(schalter):
    entprellungs_puffer = 0
    schalter_puffer = 0
    for i in range(1, 11):
        entprellungs_puffer = entprellungs_puffer +1
        schalter_puffer = schalter_puffer + schalter
        time.sleep(0.05)
        if entprellungs_puffer == schalter_puffer:
            print("entprellt")
            return 1
        else:
            return 0

while True:
    if(GPIO.input(SWITCH)):
        j = entprellen(GPIO.input(SWITCH))

        if (j):
            GPIO.output(RELAI,GPIO.LOW)
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print("pose!")
            print("SNAP")
            gpout = subprocess.check_output("gphoto2 --capture-image-and-download --filename /home/pi/photobooth_images/photobooth%H%M%S.jpg", stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
            print(gpout)
            print("please wait while your photos print...")

            subprocess.call("sudo /home/pi/scripts/photobooth/assemble_and_print", shell=True)

            time.sleep(10)
            print("ready for next round")
            GPIO.output(RELAI,GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: Try creating a simple program first that justs sets up the GPIO, sets it to high, sleeps a bit, then sets it low. At least that way you can verify your wiring is ok.

Comment: i tried that already but no change. when a use a new GPIO wich i did not used bevore it ist first off. then i start the script and it will turn on. but will not turn off again. thats the problem

Comment: i tried this again but no diffrence:import RPi.GPIO as GPIO, time, os, subprocess, signal


# GPIO setup




GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

RELAI = 19
GPIO.setup(RELAI, GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.output(RELAI, GPIO.LOW)

Comment: If you've set up a basic test as @JohnnyMopp suggested, and that isn't even working, you're likely wiring things up incorrectly. Do you understand what physical pin you're to be connecting to in the various modes (BCM in this example)? BCM mode (as opposed to BOARD) has different meanings between different revisions of the Pi hardware itself. What Pi are you on? Can you provide a schematic?

Comment: Please se my answer @stevieb

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @stevieb and @johnny Mopp 
Yes i understand the diffrence between the BCM ond BOARD mode. actually it was possible to run. 
the Problem was : i connect it like here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TVR2SCMN8xY but it did not work. then i tried to change form 5 to 3.3V on the pi and it worked. the problem is the relay is not switching properly. i red on many sides very diffrent thinks about the relays. so i dont no really what to do. i bougth now two relays :

this is the first one :
https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B01G1ENSTS/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o03__o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

thats almost the same but diffrent brand:
https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B00UFW1YNK/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01__o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1
i hoped the second one is better because its the same one as shown in the tutorial. but no changes. 
now i bought this one :
https://www.ebay.de/itm/252993630298
it has one pin to supply the coil directly with the 5V and the 3.3 is for switching.

do you think it will work or do you have other ideas ????

Thank you for your help!